# I want to ignore error alerts in C# DataGridview

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am using C# DatagridView and I am getting this error.

Here is log

```
Consulte o final desta mensagem para obter detalhes sobre como chamar a 
depuração just-in-time (JIT) em vez desta caixa de diálogo.

************** Texto de Exceção **************
System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
   em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.GetErrorText(Int32 rowIndex)
   em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow)
   em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
   em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
   em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

i want to ignore this error because they show error alerts.
How can I fix it?

Comment: You should fix rather than ignore. Use your debugger to find which `null` object you are trying to access in the grid's events.

Comment: I just want to add try-catch on that part .

Comment: _I just want to add try-catch on that part _ Which is? We need to see it. Edit and post the relevant code.